# Get icon from website, show and update icon

Tags: java, image

I was thinking the other day how could I get the icon from a website and make it show and update when it is updated on the site so I made this code:

```
URL url2 = null;     
boolean updateIcon = true;
try {
    url2 = new URL("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/70rhm66myw8ay2v/Perception%20Logo.png");
} catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
    updateIcon = false;
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
if (updateIcon) {
    System.out.println("[Perception] Icon updated.");
    if (ComputerCheck.isWindows()) {
        Image bimg = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(url2);
        this.setIconImage(bimg);
    } else if (ComputerCheck.isMac()) {
        Application application = Application.getApplication();
        Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(url2);
        application.setDockIconImage(image);  
    }
}
```

And it works 100% fine but it makes the startup time a lot slower. I was wondering how could I optimize this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd restructure this code significantly. The first thing I'd do is move the image-retrieval into a separate method and the image placing would then be "simpler"..

Compare your code against:

```
Image image = getRemoteLogo();
if (image != null) {
    // Logo updated
    updateLogo(image);
}
```

This is largely reimagining what you're doing, and depending on how you prefer it, you might move the nullcheck into `updateLogo`.

This allows you to hide the image and get rid of the IMO .. clunky null-initialization before the try-block:

```
private Image getRemoteLogo() {
    try {
       URL remoteUrl = new URL(Config.getRemoteLogoUrl());
       return Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(remoteUrl);
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
       // this is the point where you can slap the programmer :D
       ex.printStackTrace();
       return null;
    }
}
```

This neatly hides the hardcoded dropbox URL in a (not further specified) Configuration, which allows changing the logo location without having to replace classes.

Also it cleanly abstracts away the Image-loading and has clear behavior in error cases. It also gets rid of the superfluous boolean flag you have.

The `updateLogo(Image)` is history then, you do your `ComputerCheck` and set the image accordingly.

The startup slowdown is something you'll have to live with.

Oh and I changed the variable names slightly. Use speaking names wherever possible, future maintainers (including yourself) may not be able to map out which number corresponds to which URL :)

Answer (score 3):

I'd personally go one step further than the previous answer. I hate null-checking and therefore passing null as arguments and/or as return value. The only reason for me to do that would be if it was in an environment where performance is **very** important. This does not appear to be the case here. So here's my take:

```
public void tryToUpdateLogo(URL remoteUrl)
{
    try{
        updateLogo(remoteURL);
    }
    catch(MalformedURLException, UnknownSystemException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        // HANDLE ERROR
    }
}
private void updateLogo() throws MalformedURLException
{
    Image logo = getLogoFromURL(URL remoteUrl);
    UpdateLogo(logo);
}
private Image getLogoFromURL(URL remoteURL)
{
    return Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(remoteUrl);
}
private void updateLogo(Image logo) throws UnknownSystemException
{
    System.out.println("[Perception] Icon updated.");

    if(ComputerCheck.isWindows())
        this.setIconImage(logo);
    else if(ComputerCheck.isMac())
        getMACApplication().setDockIconImage(logo);
    else
        throw new UnknownSystemException();
}
```

This code is based on the premise that "Error handling is a responsability", which due to the SRP (Single Responsability Principle) is supposed to be separated from the code as is described in Robert C. Martins [Clean Code](http://www.amazon.de/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882) .